# app crashes when transitioning to original scene swift sprite kit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am building an app that transitions to an end scene when two object collide. That part works just fine, but when i try to transition back to the original scene with the restart button on the end scene.The app crashes. It makes it back to the original scene but crashes immediately.The the line that is selected in the debugger is where i declare the physics body of one of the objects that collide(works fine first run. I have seen this error many times. But no one can give me an answer of how to fix it. Here is the code where i transition from the original seen to the end scene

```
func mineSubCrash(Mine : SKSpriteNode, subm: SKSpriteNode){
  subm.removeFromParent()
  Mine.removeFromParent()
  self.view?.presentScene(RestartScene())
}
```

very basic, here is the transition back

```
func restart(){
  restartButton.removeFromSuperview()
  self.view?.presentScene(GameScene(), transition: SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(0.3))
}
```

I dont understand why it crashes. must be something with me not ending the original scene right . I have had this problem with other apps i have tried to make. help needed and appreciated!!

Comment: why to you have parenthesis or brackets after your scene name?

Comment: could it possibly be trying to add two physics bodies to the same object . How do you completely shutdown everything in a view?